# Compiling the mysql_fdw for postgresql?

Tags: compiling, mysql, postgresql

I'm attempting to compile the [MySQL Foreign Data Wrapper for Postgresql 9.1+](http://pgxn.org/dist/mysql_fdw/), on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and having a fair bit of trouble getting it to work.

So far I've managed to use git to [download the source from github](http://github.com/dpage/mysql_fdw/), and based on the instructions add the following to my `/etc/profile` path in the hopes that this thing will compile:

```
# ^ The rest of the file ^
# POSTGRESQL Environment Vars
export PGDATA="/usr/local/pgsql/data"
export PGHOST="localhost"
export PGPORT="5432"
export PGLOG="/var/log/pgsql"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin:/opt/lampp/bin
```

I then per the documentation I ran

```
$ make USE_PGXS=1
gcc -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DLINUX_OOM_ADJ=0 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -fpic -I/usr/include/mysql -I. -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/include/tcl8.5  -c -o mysql_fdw.o mysql_fdw.c
mysql_fdw.c: In function ‘mysqlPlanForeignScan’:
mysql_fdw.c:467:8: warning: ‘rows’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
gcc -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DLINUX_OOM_ADJ=0 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -fpic -shared -o mysql_fdw.so mysql_fdw.o -L/usr/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu  -Wl,--as-needed  -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -ldl
```

And aside from the warning I suppose it compiled ok...
Next I tried to install it, and I get a couple of errors about some missing files...

```
$ sudo make USE_PGPX=1 install
Makefile:35: ../../src/Makefile.global: No such file or directory
Makefile:36: /contrib/contrib-global.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/contrib/contrib-global.mk'.  Stop.
```

Do I need to compile all of Postgres and include this extension in the source?  Because the sources seem to be referring to a directory above the one that I'm in.

Comment: And if this belongs in the DBA stack exchange feel free to send it over there.

Comment: Looks like `sudo` is changing the current working directory, or `pg_config` isn't on your path as the `sudo`'d user. Did you modify your `PATH` for your normal user?

Comment: Nope just my `/etc/profile` for my system.  That makes a difference I take it...even when I run with `sudo`...?

Comment: hmm I ran the initial `make` with `sudo` and the `make install` with `sudo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo.

```
sudo make USE_PGPX=1 install
              ^^^^
              PGXS
```

Comment: What's the `USE_PGPX` var for anyway?

Comment: It enables out-of-tree extension compilation using the PG extension building tool. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-pgxs.html